# Luminosity level issue and suspend issue when closing the lid

Tags: suspend, laptop

I have a Dell Vostro 3500. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I had some problems. I tried to solve these issues through the solutions here but nothing seems to work :

the first issue :
That i can't change Luminosity level from my keyboard <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd>)

the second issue : 
When I close the lid, the system won't suspend; the fan is still running, and when i reopen the lid, I get a black screen and nothing seem to work and everything crashes.

I thought maybe my Nvdia Driver is buggy so I tried to change it and I tried some commands to fix it but nothing seem to work so i installed 16.10 but I had the same issue.

Finally I tried Open Suse 42.1 and I still had the same problem.

How can I fix this? Should I install an older version?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might its a nvidia driver issue, try change the driver in:
System configuration>System and updates>aditional drivers (I havent system in english, but i might in english have names like that)

This solved the issues in my laptop, but if u cant solve the trouble with that, u can install the privative driver seeing this guide:
[Install latest Nvidia driver in Ubuntu](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: are you sure about this cause i think i tried this tuto but it didn't work :'(

Comment: This worked for me, but that happened to me in AMD graphic card.
I solved changing the driver in the System configuration.
Sorry if i couldnt help you.